# Reflect Annotation of an Instance of my own Class

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, runtime, java-annotations

I have several Classes A1,A2,A3 which extend the abstract class myA. These classes have x fields of class B. The fields of class B are annotated with the annotation Test.(Test is available at runtime) How can i get the annotation Test and its value from inside a method of class B.

```
public class A1 extends myA{

    @Test("all")
    private B b1;

    @Test("none")
    private B b2;

    @Test("none")
    private B b3;

    //....

    public void interact(){
        b2.doSomethingBasedOnMyAnnotation();
    }

}
public class A2 extends myA{

    @Test("none")
    private B b;

    //....
}

public class B{

     public void doSomethingBasedOnMyAnnotation(){
        // How to reach the Annotation from here ?
     }

}

@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Test{
    String value() default "all";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you place an annotation on a variable, it becomes a static property of that variable, not of the object you can reach through that variable. Consider:

```
public class A1 extends myA{

    @Test("all")
    private B b1=new B();

    @Test("none")
    private B b2=b1;

    //....

    public void interact(){
        // this
        b2.doSomethingBasedOnMyAnnotation();
        // is exactly the same as
        b1.doSomethingBasedOnMyAnnotation();
    }
}
```

It’s not even valid to assume that there is an annotated variable involved. What about
`new B().doSomethingBasedOnMyAnnotation()`?

Since fields are resolved at compile-time, there is no abstraction in your desired operation anyway. If you know that you are going to invoke, `b2.doSomethingBasedOnMyAnnotation();`, you already know which field you’re using and there’s no problem of providing the annotation value of `b2` as parameter to the invoked method, rather than expecting the receiver to magically find out. E.g.

```
public class B{
    public void doSomething(String arg){
    }
}
public class A1 extends myA{

    @Test("all")
    private B b1;

    @Test("none")
    private B b2;

    //....

    public void interact(){
        b1.doSomething(get("b1"));
        b2.doSomething(get("b2"));
    }
    static String get(String fieldName) {
        try {
            return A1.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
                .getAnnotation(Test.class).value();
        } catch(NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

though we could happily work without Reflection:

```
public class A1 extends myA{

    static final String TEST_B1="all";

    @Test(TEST_B1)
    private B b1;

    static final String TEST_B2="none";

    @Test(TEST_B2)
    private B b2;

    static final String TEST_B3="none";

    @Test(TEST_B3)
    private B b3;

    //....

    public void interact(){
        b1.doSomething(TEST_B1);
        b2.doSomething(TEST_B2);
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure that the caller can’t pass the wrong argument by accident, use encapsulation instead:

```
public final class EncapsulatedB {
    final String testValue;
    B b;
    EncapsulatedB(String value) {
        this(value, null);
    }
    EncapsulatedB(String value, B initialB) {
        testValue=value;
        b=initialB;
    }
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        b.doSomething(testValue);
    }
}

public class A1 extends myA{
    private final EncapsulatedB b1=new EncapsulatedB("all");
    private final EncapsulatedB b2=new EncapsulatedB("none");
    private final EncapsulatedB b3=new EncapsulatedB("none");

    //....

    public void interact(){
        b1.doSomething();
        b2.doSomething();
    }
}
```